# Drive API Error Python: FileNotFoundError 'credentials.json'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Brand new to anything regarding programming! Please treat me like I know absolutely nothing. I followed the Google Docs API quickstart for python. I am getting the error of

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'

From my understanding, this is because the file path is incorrect, but I have no clue how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the source code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly']

# The ID of a sample document.
DOCUMENT_ID = '195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE'


def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
Prints the title of a sample document.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh 
tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes 
for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', 
SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user 
log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

try:
    service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
    document = 
service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()

    print('The title of the document is: 
{}'.format(document.get('title')))
except HttpError as err:
    print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()}
```

Comment: Where do you have the file stored? Do you have many folders in the project?

Comment: The file is stored "My files/Linux files/quickstart.py" (quickstart is what I named it.
The project I would like to use this function in is stored "My files/Linux files/MaintenanceApp"

Comment: Have you tried the solution below? The first part of it add-it under the `SCOPES` line and the other part, the `flow` one is already on the code you just need to modify it. Also, why don't you have all the files under the same folder as is intended on the quickstart?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the absolute path to the file.  Try with a variable like this.

```
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = r'C:\Users\ME\client_secret.json'
```

Then add that to your code.

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE , SCOPES)
```

Comment: What line of code should I add those two lines? Should I use the file path I commented above? I'm not sure how it works since I am using a chromebook.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but one step back, I didn't know how to ***create the credentials.json*** file.  (Most users will probably just need to go to step 5 and rename the json you downloaded to **credentials.json**.)

Create an API Key using steps [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials?authuser=3#oauth-client-id)  (note that the OAuth is different than the other API keys).  These same steps are outlined below with screenshots:

1. Open the Google Cloud [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?authuser=3).
2. At the top-left, click Menu menu

   > APIs & Services > Credentials. [Step 2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyJkw.png)
3. Click +Create Credentials > OAuth client ID. [step 3 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWbTS.png)
4. Click Application type > Desktop app. [step 4 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3bfp.png) In the "Name"
   field, type a name for the credential. This name is only shown in
   the Google Cloud console.  NOTE: Users WILL see this name the 1st
   time they give permission to the app in Google's warning dialog.
   [step 5 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adL0a.png)
5. Click Create. The OAuth client created screen
   appears, showing your new Client ID and Client secret.  --- Before
   you Click OK ---  You can download the json file here. [screenshot
   to download the json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkNyF.png)
6. Click OK. The newly created credential appears under "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs."

Finally, rename the json to credentials.json and move it to the folder where your app is running from (or give your app the right path the file).

Answer (score 0):

If you copy files/ project folders, hard coded links will be lost.
Try getting the current directory and supplying that info to the variable looking for credentials.json. (that file is in the working directory right?)

```
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        CURR_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        credential_file=str(CURR_DIR)+'/credentials.json'  #may need backslash in windows, IDK
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            credential_file, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```